# When calling a function that returns a function that returns a function, how do you get data at the bottom?

Tags: javascript, function, callback

How can I access the data from  the function inside the function inside the function I'm returning?

```
projectsRsrc.factory('projectsSrvc', ['$resource', function($resource){

    return function(name){
        var url = "http://localhost/proj/v3/apiSimulations/projects.json"; 
        var resource = $resource(url);
        return resource.get(function(data){
            return data;
        });
    }
}]);
```

I want to get this data in my controller.

```
projectsApp.controller('projectsCtrl', ['$scope', 'projectsSrvc', function($scope, projectsSrvc){

    $scope.projects = projectsSrvc(name);
}
```

But `projectsSrvc` returns a function, and I'm not really sure how to access the function it is returning. Ultimately I want the `data` to be assigned in my controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your factory returns a function and that function returns a <s>promise</s> so in your controller your code should be like this:

```
projectsSrvc(name).then(function(data) {
   $scope.projects = data;
});
```

Edit: I mixed up $resource with $http so things seem a little different, however everything is explained here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

I got it to work by changing the code to this:

```
projectsSrvc(name).$promise.then(function(data) {
   $scope.projects = data;
});
```

Tested here: http://jsbin.com/vepivacosa/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Should I change my factory at all?

Comment: I'm still getting `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: If it works and it fulfills all your requirements I dont see a reason why you should change it. The only thing I dont get is why you pass in the parameter `name` when you never use it.

Comment: It doesnt work. It seems `projectsSrvc(name)` is not returning a promise. I was using `name` in my real version where it's used in the URL.

Comment: WORKED! Thanks a ton! How did you figure that out??

Answer (score 0):

You just need another set of parantheses

```
$scope.projects = projectsSrvc(name)(argumentmustbepassedhereforthefunction);
```

But note that you'll need some callback kind of thing(or promises may be?) as you're returning from the ajax call which is asynchronous.

BTW the above code is just a one-liner for

```
var func = projectsSrvc(name); // store the function reference
$.scope.projects = func(argumentmustbepassedhereforthefunction);
```

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: object is not a function`